# Please help me explain the kanji in [出]{だ}した and [出]{で}た

Tags: word-choice

They seem to mean different things (they aren't different conjugations of the same word). Can someone explain why they use the same kanji? o.o
And probably the exact differences between the two?

Comment: Have you learned about intransitive vs transitive verbs, like [出]{で}る vs [出]{だ}す, 始まる vs 始める, [開]{あ}く vs [開]{あ}ける, 閉まる vs 閉める?

Answer (score 2):

出す（だす;da-su）means to take out, or to put out.

出る（でる;de-ru）means to go out, to leave, etc.

They both share the same Kanji root because the meaning of the kanji is directly related to both of these verbs; both dasu and deru have something to do with "out," going out, putting out, etc.

Usually these two verbs are taught together as transitive and intransitive pairs.

Transitive verbs take a direct object.

Intransitive verbs don't take a direct object.

You can usually tell the difference between them with a simple test: ask what you are verb-ing. if it makes sense then it's a transitive verb.

EX: You eat what?
I eat an apple.

Here apple is the direct object. The verb takes a direct object, therefore it is a transitive verb.

They are two different words, as *go out* and *take out* mean different things in English too. So if it's easier to learn them as separate and complete words, rather than as transitive/intransitive pairs, then go for it.

Answer (score 1):

The both use the same kanji because they are the same in **essence**, the meaning will be something roughly like **Something/someone left a place**.

- **出す** is a transitive verb which means **to take out(something, from the place it was)**.
  　　e.g. 引き出しから眼鏡を出して下さい。 Please take out the glasses from the drawer.
- **出る** is an intransitive verb which means **to leave(someplace, where the person was)**.
  　　e.g. 夜に成ると月が出ました。The moon came out when the night arrived.

Answer (score 1):

出す(dasu): to take something out.
出る(deru): to go out of someplace.

私はゴミを出した。watashi wa gomi wo dashita.
I took the garbage out.

私は家を出た。watashi wa ie wo deta.
I left the house.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you know the difference of their meaning so I just don't bother to explain either of their meaning.

It is just that Chinese do not differ meaning of words in this way. So if you're the one to choose a Chinese word here you may have to create a new word for one of them but that is not very like the traditional way.

By the way, Chinese use preposition to differ these two kinds of meaning.

So to be more specific, check http://kanji.jitenon.jp/sp/kanji/035.html , you can see that both 出す(だした) and 出る(出た) are there.

Comment: Hmm I think this answer lacks reference. Working on it.

Comment: Still not sure what kind of reference to add. I begin to think I might not be the best one to answer this question as I don't see the big picture here like what is the first time each word started to appear in writing Japanese or things like that.